# Link to Facebook Page Tab App with signed request Page ID

Tags: php, facebook

I now have a Page ID for my page tab app from the signed_request. I am attempting to use that Page ID as a link for Pinterest for the 'Viewer' of the Page Tab to click on. I have looked around this site and the closest thing I can find is;

```
    http://www.facebook.com/pages/@/PAGEID
```

This gets me into the users facebook wall, but not directly onto the Tab App. Is there additional information required to get me directly into the Page Tab where the app is located?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the page id and your app id. Use this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/@/PAGEID?sk=app_APPID#
```

So for example, if the page id was 987654321 and my app id was 123456789, then the link would be

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/@/987654321?sk=app_123456789#
```

Of course, you wouldn't hard-code the page id into the link, it would be a variable depending on which page the app is installed on.